# Efficiency: What data structure to use...?

Tags: data-structures, performance

I am working with a very large dataset.  Essentially I will be working with millions of records and storing a value into a dataset.

Each time that I store a value, I must first check to make sure that the value is not already in the data structure.  If the value is in the data structure, I must update (or remove/add) the record to update the count.

There are repeats within the dataset, and I don't want to use a bad data structure and get a speed of O(n), as I'd like to be able to run this overnight and come in in the morning with it done!

Any advice?

Comment: What's your platform and language?  Some solutions, like balanced trees, are awkward to write but can work great if found in a library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, a hash table is **probably** the right answer, **but** hash tables aren't terribly space efficient, so if you get to the point where you may be exhausting your memory, you should consider a sorted array of keys and a parallel sorted array of values.  Basically, if you can get access to the entire list of keys upfront, create an array of these and sort it.  Then create a parallel array of values.  Everytime you need to store something, simply do a binary search (O(log N)) to find the index in the key array, then update the corresponding index in the value array.  This will be less speed-efficient than a hash table, but will guarantee virtually no space overhead.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), combined with (possibly) a list or some specific structure. That, to me, sounds like a [database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database).

Answer (score 0):

Use a hashtable

Answer (score 0):

You could try a binary tree.  log_2(1,000,000) is about 20.  This might be better if you don't know what all the keys will be ahead of time.